# how to Add constant Zeros to a decimal number in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add constant 6 digits and 2 decimal place,
I have the following values:

```
1500.000
   1.000
766898.930
```

how can I convert these numbers to

```
001500.00
000001.00
766898.93
```

I used these codes, but nothing worked:

```
SELECT REPLACE (STR(REPLACE(cast (MonthlyPayment.LocalAmount AS NUMERIC(18,2) ) ,'.',''),9),' ',0) FROM MonthlyPayment

SELECT REPLACE (cast(cast(MonthlyPayment.LocalAmount AS NUMERIC(18,2) ) AS NCHAR(9)),' ',0) FROM MonthlyPayment
```

Please, Help

Comment: [zerofill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

Comment: What database is this? You have contradictory tags (`mysql` vs `tsql`).

Comment: `SQL` is not a database, it's a language used by many database vendors.  Did you mean SQL Server?

Comment: @sstan: They are using the database with the `MonthlyPayment` table in it.

Comment: @BishoyEzzat `SQL` isn't a DBMS.  Do you mean you are using `SQL Server`?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: I think people gave me -ve for the post ... cuz it is hard to be solved ! :D

Comment: I added the sql-server tag, because `str()` is a SQL Server function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str()` function suggests that you are using SQL Server.

```
SELECT right(replicate('0', 9) + cast(cast(MonthlyPayment.LocalAmount AS NUMERIC(9, 2) ) as varchar(10)), 9)
FROM MonthlyPayment;
```

Here are the steps:

- Convert to a numeric with two decimal points.
- Convert that value to a string.
- Pad the left of the string with enough zeros to get to 9 characters.

Comment: Are you using any Speech-To-Text software? So fast in typing!

Answer (score 0):

If 2012+ try the format function

```
Select Format(25.36,'000000.00')  returns 000025.36
Select Format(25,'000000.00')     returns 000025.00
```